# Count & Display the number of items in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I would like to display the number of item in the database.  The following is the php code:

```
$jobid = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_JOB'];
$data = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE jobid = $jobid";
$attribid = mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error);

$count = "SELECT count(*) FROM attributes WHERE jobid = $jobid";
$database_count = mysql_query($count);
//Declare the Array
$DuetiesDesc = array();

print_r ($database_count);
```

But instead of getting the desired result, I get :

> Resource id #14

Please Assist

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should get it out of the way that you shouldn't be using mysql_* see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

See the code below... explanations are in comments

```
$jobid = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_JOB'];
// escape variables using mysql_real_escape_string
$data = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE jobid =".mysql_real_escape_string($jobid);

$attrRes = mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error());

// I'm assuming you want all of the attributes return in this query in an array
$attributes = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($attrRes)){
    $attributes[] = $row;
}

// Now if you want the count we have all of the records in the attributes array;

$numAttributes = count($attributes);


// here is an example of how you can iterate through it..
print "<p>Found ".$numAttributes." attributes</p>";
print "<table>";
foreach($attributes as $row){
    print "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $cell){
        print "<td>".$cell."</td>";
    }
    print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
 $jobid = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_JOB'];
 $data = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE jobid =$jobid";
 $attribid = mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($attribid);
 echo $count;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $jobid = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_JOB'];
 $data = "SELECT *FROM attributes WHERE jobid =$jobid";
 $attribid = mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error);

 $count = "SELECT count(*) FROM attributes WHERE jobid = $jobid";
 $database_count = mysql_query($count);
 //Declare the Array
 $DuetiesDesc = array();
 $database_count=mysql_fetch_assoc($database_count);
 echo $database_count['count(*)'];
```